# Using Amazon's Java Alexa Skill Kit, can I put a custom Java object into a session attribute?

Tags: java, session, attributes, alexa-skills-kit

I'm using the Alexa Skill Kit for Java to build a custom Skill.  I am trying to use a custom session attribute, `co.prosody.util.PaInputData`, in `com.amazon.speech.speechlet.Session`.

No trouble with `session.setAttribute("inputData", paInputData)`, but when I retrieve the attribute `(PaInputData)session.getAttribute("inputData")`, I get a class cast exception:

> "errorMessage": "java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to co.prosody.util.PaInputData"

Is it possible to get my object back?

Answer (score 2):

Attribute objects that belong to the session that are not Strings will be turned into Linked Hash Maps, mapping the name of each instance variable to that of its value. For Objects that are not too complex, you can simply fetch these values by accessing each key of the Linked Hash Map that is associated with this object that belongs to your session's attributes, and reconstruct the object that way. (Note that you will need getters associated with your instance variables) You will not, however, be able to directly cast whatever object was stored in the attributes of your session to the object you desire/expect.

So let's say, for example, I have an Dog object, with two fields:

```
public class Dog{
    private String name = "Spot";
    private int age = 20;
    public Dog(){

    }
    public Dog(String nIn, int aIn){
        name = nIn;
        age = aIn;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }


}
```

If this was stored in my session's attributes with a key of "MY_DOG", I could reconstruct the object this way:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> myDog = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>)session.getAttribute("MY_DOG");
String fetchedName = (String)myDog.get("name"); //this will return "Spot"
int fetchedAge = (Integer)myDog.get("age"); //this will return 20
Dog copyDog = new Dog(fetchedName, age);//effectively copies the Dog object
```